# Why are the Ionic keyboard events not firing?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to execute some code when the keyboard pops up and when it hides. I've placed it in the main MyAppComponent because I want the code to execute on any app page, but for some reason none of the keyboard events are working. What am I doing wrong?

```
...
import { Keyboard, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyAppComponent {

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public keyboard: Keyboard) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            this.keyboard.didShow.subscribe(() => {
                // This is never executed...
                console.log('Keyboard is now open');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried using `onKeyboardShow` from ionic-native, but that did not execute its code either.

```
...
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

export class MyAppComponent {

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public keyboard: Keyboard) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() => {
                // This is never executed...
                console.log('Keyboard is now open');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Ionic info dump:

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v9.11.1
    npm               : 5.8.0 
    OS                : Linux 4.13
```

The cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard plugin (version 2.0.5) is installed, added to the appModule and present in config.xml

I'm testing the app on a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0, it uses the default Samsung keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use keyboard events like below;

```
  window.addEventListener('keyboardWillShow', (e) => {}); 
  window.addEventListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {});
  window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => {}); 
  window.addEventListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {});
```

Comment: Yeap, couldn't get `onKeyboardShow()` to work with Ionic app. Used `window` object instead.

Answer (score 2):

For **Ionic 4 Keyboard Native Plugin** try using **addEventListener**

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardWillShow', () => {
  console.log("Keyboard will Show");
});
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
  console.log("Keyboard is Shown");
});
window.addEventListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {
  console.log("Keyboard will Hide");
});
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
  console.log("Keyboard is Hidden");
});
```

**Check complete tutorial code [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-keyboard-native-plugin-tutorial/)**

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2306, it seems like the keyboard plugins are somewhat broken at the time of writing.

```
...
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyAppComponent {

    constructor(public platform: Platform) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            Observable.fromEvent(window, 'keyboardWillShow').subscribe(() => {
                console.log('Keyboard is now open');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Credit to https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2306#issuecomment-372593829 for the solution that worked for me!